# Webpack 4 + bootstrap [TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have recently started working with webpack, the build is working just fine

While running my app with webpack I am getting below mentioned error - this is occurring in the Bootstrap package internally:

```
var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.'); ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
at Object.jQueryDetection
```

I am using expose-loader. My webpack File:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('server-build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: {
          exposes: ['$', 'jQuery'],
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

Here is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^2.4.4",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.4.4",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^13.5.1",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "amd-loader": "0.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "pm2": "^4.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primereact": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "sharethis-reactjs": "^1.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "start:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "ssr": "node -r esm server/server.js",
    "new-build": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=development -w",
    "dev-start": "nodemon ./server-build/index.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.3",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "colibrio-reader-framework": "file:framework",
    "expose-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

Please assist with this particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `html-loader` to evaluate the HTML template you should not add the `<script src="app.js">` tag (or whatever you choose to name your app entrypoint).
Webpack adds it on its own at the end, and if the loader finds one it goes into evaluating the JS, thus leading to various Bootstrap errors.